# Getting an error run script in Google Collab

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I have a code that worked fine in Jupyter notebook but is not working in Google Collab. I am trying to figure out what the problem is. Is it the fact that Google Collab is using a different version of python? Is it the dictionary loop. Is it something else.

The code is as follows:

```
stocksv = ['AAPL', 'NDAQ']
returnsall=data1['Adj Close'].pct_change()
returnsall = returnsall.dropna()*100
stock= stocksv[2:3]
# using list comprehension

listToStr1 = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in stock])

# Get a bool series representing which row satisfies the condition i.e. True for
# row in which value of 'Age' column is more than 30
stock= listToStr1
values= [2,5,10,15,20]
print('This year: \n')
for z in values:
    seriesObj = returnsall.apply(lambda x: True if x[stock] > z else False , axis=1)
# Count number of True in series
    numOfRows = len(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
    print('$',stock, ' has been up more than ',z, '%',' on ', numOfRows, ' days', sep='')
```

> This year:

> ---
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
> 2897             try:
> -> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> 2899             except KeyError as err:

> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

> KeyError: ''

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> 8 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, > key, method, tolerance)
> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> 2899             except KeyError as err:
> -> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
> 2901
> 2902         if tolerance is not None:

> KeyError: ''

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The code you provided doesn't define `listToStr1` or `returnsall`.

Comment: @saiden ok. Thank You for the feedback. I have just reposted this question for definite variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70229526/why-am-i-getting-an-error-run-script-in-google-collab

Comment: @saiden I have modified this. Didn't know there was a way to modify. thanks.

Comment: What dataset are you using?

Comment: @saiden finance. I get stock data from yfinance.